# Android - Write a KML a file From URL(my webserver) and save it to my android device

Tags: android, webserver, kml

I have a kml file in my webserver

For ex http://mysite.com/example.kml

In my app i have to download the kml file from my webserver and Show it locally in my android device.

How can i get the kml file from webserver to my android device.I think the better way is to read and write the file to my android device from webserver and save it as example.kml file.I am a new babie to android.

I would appreciate the insight on how to implement this.